# How to make Seaborn histogram have skinny bars / bins

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram, visualization

How can the following skinny look in a histogram, taken from an article, be achieved based on the Python code below? The histogram bins are noticeably smaller than the plot I made at the bottom. There is also spacing between the bars and no `edgecolor` outline

[image]

```
from scipy.stats import dgamma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
r = dgamma.rvs(1.1, size=1000)
sns.set_style("white")
sns.set_context("talk")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(24,12))
sns.histplot(r, color='deepskyblue', stat='density')
sns.kdeplot(r, color='orange')
plt.title('Seaborn Histplot Example', size=24, fontweight='bold')
sns.histplot(r, color='deepskyblue', stat='density', edgecolor="black")
sns.kdeplot(r, color='orange')
plt.axvline(2.8, 0, 0.95, color='blue')
plt.axvline(2.4, 0, 0.95, color='brown', linestyle='--')
ax.tick_params(left=True, bottom=True)
plt.show()
```

The code above looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]You can supply a `shrink` argument to your `histplot()` function in seaborn. Also to get rid of the edge color, you can simply remove the `edgecolor="black"` that you have included in your function call above?

Does this do what you're after?

`sns.histplot(r, color='deepskyblue', stat='density', shrink=0.8)`

I've also defined a number of bins in the attached image using `bins=100`

Comment: any idea what the default setting `bins='auto'` does/calculates? scaling skinny bars for small sample data instead of the example used above has been tricky. documentation only says "bins: "Generic bin parameter that can be the name of a reference rule, the number of bins, or the breaks of the bins. Passed to `numpy.histogram_bin_edges()`." https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html

Comment: The notes section on this page explains how bin edges are calculated in `numpy`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram_bin_edges.html#numpy.histogram_bin_edges.

Comment: To be clear, `shrink` controls only the visual representation: the proportion of the allotted bin occupied by the bar. To change the computation itself, use `bins` or `binwidth`.